# Difference between Higgs and anti-Higgs Fields

Tags: particle-physics

I'm assuming the LHC can create a Higgs and an anti-Higgs boson. If so, would their fields be identical with respect to mass effects? How would LHC detectors distinguish between the two bosons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Higgs is a **real** scalar field, so there's **no** "anti-Higgs" particle. All imaginary part of initial complex doublet are absorbed by the weak gauge bosons (Ws and Z), only a real scalar field remains after this.

Comment: Leandro: I think I understand from your answer that the field remains the same. But isn't it true then, that similarly to a neutrino and an anti-neutrino, an anti-Higgs boson and a Higgs boson are identical particles?

Comment: @Michael: neutrino is not really a good analogy. Think about photons rather. In any case, it's up to you (and dictionary) whether you think that photon is its own antiparticle or that it doesn't have an antiparticle. It doesn't change physics.

Comment: Yes, the antiparticle of the Higgs boson is the same Higgs boson. That's why we don't have an independent word "anti-Higgs" in the dictionary because that would be redundant. So the term "anti-Higgs" in your title and question may "exist" and may be interpreted in some way - it means nothing else than the same Higgs - but it is not an actual term in physics. At any rate, because there's no "other" particle, it's obvious that the LHC can't distinguish between the two particles (which are the same particle), just like I can't distinguish Michael Luciuk and Michael Luciuk.

Comment: Your statement is valid only after spontaneous symmetry breaking. Before SSB, the Higgs field is a doublet of complex scalar fields. Since the fields are complex, you have particle and antiparticle.